# Save Excel Worksheet as CSV with null and semicolon as separator

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I'm exporting an Excel.Worksheet in C# like this:

```
myWorksheet.SaveAs(myPath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV);
```

it works almost ok, but I need to force two things:

- The "field separator" should be semicolon (;). I'm getting a comma (,)
- The "text separator" should always be null. I'm getting double quotes ("")

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlfileformat%28v=office.11%29.aspx) is totally unhelpful (what the hell is "xlTextWindows: Specifies a type of text format." supposed to mean?)

Any idea?

Comment: you are getting a comma for your field separator because that is what the "c" in CSV stands for. Although I'm not familiar with the long list of Excel built-in formats, I think it is likely that you won't find something exactly suiting your needs. If this is a one-time operation, it would be fairly simple to do a global search-and-replace to accomplish this task. Is this something that you will need to do repeatedly? You tagged this with C# -- are you interested in some C# code to do the post-process search-and-replace?

Comment: `xlTextWindows` is one of a number of constants that define the newline character or characters.  Windows used CR LF.  With Excel, Save Workbook as CSV does not place double quotes around a text field unless it contains a comma.  Either C# is different or you have commas in your fields.  I understand Excel will use semicolon as the CSV separator if the decimal separator is specified as comma.  This is normally a national setting but C# has functionality to allow temporary national settings which may be worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys, but I was looking for something a little less clumsy.

Anyway, since I was just a step away from closing the project, I put together an inelegant but working solution like this:

```
static public void WorksheetToCSV(Excel.Worksheet origine, string CSVoutPath, string fieldSeparator, string textSeparator)
    {
        Excel.Range rngCurrentRow;
        string lineaDaScrivere;
        TextWriter csv = new StreamWriter(CSVoutPath);


        for (int i = 1; i <= origine.UsedRange.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            rngCurrentRow = origine.UsedRange.get_Range("A" + i, "A" + i).EntireRow;
            lineaDaScrivere="";

            foreach (Excel.Range cella in rngCurrentRow.Columns)
            {
                try
                {
                    lineaDaScrivere = lineaDaScrivere + textSeparator + cella.Value.ToString() + textSeparator + fieldSeparator;
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException ex)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            lineaDaScrivere=lineaDaScrivere.Substring(0, (lineaDaScrivere.Length - fieldSeparator.Length));

           csv.WriteLine(lineaDaScrivere);
        }

        csv.Close();
    }
```

There are better solution, but this worked as expected for me.

Comment: Don't write your own CSV parser/generator. There are [libraries](http://www.filehelpers.com/) that handle all the kinks for you. In your case: you are not escaping your characters which could result in incorrect CSV output.

Answer (score 1):

The VBA (not C#) solution to replace the commas with semicolons is:

```
Sub CreateCSV()

Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRow As Range
Dim sOutput As String
Dim sFname As String, lFnum As Long

'Open a text file to write
sFname = "C:\MyCsv.csv"
lFnum = FreeFile

Open sFname For Output As lFnum
'Loop through the rows'
    For Each rRow In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
    'Loop through the cells in the rows'
    For Each rCell In rRow.Cells
        sOutput = sOutput & rCell.Value & ";"
    Next rCell
     'remove the last comma'
    sOutput = Left(sOutput, Len(sOutput) - 1)

    'write to the file and reinitialize the variables'
    Print #lFnum, sOutput
    sOutput = ""
 Next rRow

'Close the file'
Close lFnum

End Sub
```

[source](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showpost.php?p=1724209&postcount=5) tested and works. Now, I'm not sure what text separator you're speaking about being `""` but I haven't run into that. If you go the VBA way, let me know if that's still happening and we will alter the code. If this VBA solution is completely useless to you, I apologize!